# Como guardo el estado de una actividad con sharedpreferences?

Tags: android-studio, activity, sharedpreferences

quiero saber como hago para guardar el estado de mis actividades, por ejemplo si voy en el nivel 2, osea en la activity 2, como hago para guardar el textview que indica el nivel, por ejemplo nivel2, y que al cerrar la app y volverla abrir, al darle click en el boton jugar en la Mainactivity me cargue la activity 2 o la actividad en donde halla quedado, o en su defecto si es la primera vez que juego y/o si quede en el nivel 1 pues que al darle click en jugar me cargue la actividad 1.

Quiero hacerlo con shared preferences.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de mi activity1 llamado nivel 1:

```
public class Nivel1 extends Activity {



    public static Button r1,r2,r3,r4;
    static TextView npregunta;
    public static TextView preguntas,nivelactual;
    public static ImageView fotoperfil;
    public static Activity fa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nivel1);
        fa=this;
        preguntas=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.preguntas);
        nivelactual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nivelactual);
        fotoperfil=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fotoperfil);
        r1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta1);
        r2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta2);
        r3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta3);
        r4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta4);
        npregunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.npregunta);
        Preferencias.setLevel(getApplicationContext(), 1);
        r1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("2")){
                startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }

                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("3")
                       ){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }

                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, popupc.class);
                Intent i7 = new Intent(Nivel1.this, Transicion1.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("4") ){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else if(npregunta.getText().toString().equals("5")){

                    startActivity(i7);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int peticion, int codigo, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(peticion,codigo,data);
        if(peticion==1 && codigo==RESULT_OK)
{

            String resultado=data.getStringExtra("tpregunta");
            npregunta.setText(resultado);
            if(resultado.equals("2")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta2));
                r1.setText("respuesta21");
                r2.setText("respuesta22");
                r3.setText("respuesta23");
                r4.setText("respuesta24");}
            else if(resultado.equals("3")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta3));
                r1.setText("respuesta31");
                r2.setText("respuesta32");
                r3.setText("respuesta33");
                r4.setText("respuesta34");

            }
            else if(resultado.equals("4")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta4));
                r1.setText("respuesta41");
                r2.setText("respuesta42");
                r3.setText("respuesta43");
                r4.setText("respuesta44");

            }
            else if(resultado.equals("5")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta5));
                r1.setText("respuesta51");
                r2.setText("respuesta52");
                r3.setText("respuesta53");
                r4.setText("respuesta54");

            }


        }


    }

}
```

Este es el de mi activity 2:

```
public class Nivel2 extends Activity {

    private Nivel1 cx= new Nivel1();
    public static Button r1,r2,r3,r4;
    static TextView npregunta;
    public static TextView preguntas,nivelactual;
    public static ImageView fotoperfil;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nivel2);
        cx.fa.finish();
        preguntas=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.preguntas);
        nivelactual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nivelactual);
        fotoperfil=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fotoperfil);
        r1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta1);
        r2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta2);
        r3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta3);
        r4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta4);
        npregunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.npregunta);
        Preferencias.setLevel(getApplicationContext(), 2 /* Nivel */);
        r1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popupn.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("7")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }

                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popupn.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("6")
                        ){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }

                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Nivel2.this, popupn.class);
                Intent i7=new Intent(Nivel2.this, popup.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("8") ){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int peticion, int codigo, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(peticion, codigo, data);
        if (peticion == 1 && codigo == RESULT_OK) {

            String resultado=data.getStringExtra("tpregunta");
            npregunta.setText(resultado);

            if(resultado.equals("7")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta7));
                r1.setText("respuesta71");
                r2.setText("respuesta72");
                r3.setText("respuesta73");
                r4.setText("respuesta74");

            }
            else if(resultado.equals("8")){
                preguntas.setText(getText(R.string.pregunta8));
                r1.setText("respuesta81");
                r2.setText("respuesta82");
                r3.setText("respuesta83");
                r4.setText("respuesta84");

            }
        }


    }
}
```

y este es el código de mi Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button botoninfo,botonsonido,botonjugar;
    int contador,img,img2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sonidoboton = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.teleport3);
        botoninfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.informacion);
        botonsonido = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sonido);
        botonjugar= (Button)findViewById(R.id.comenzar);
        botoninfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                teleport.start();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, info.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        botonjugar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                botonsonido.start();
                switch (Preferencias.getLevel(getApplicationContext())){

                    case 0:

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent intentnivel1=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Nivel1.class);
                        startActivity(intentnivel1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent intentnivel2=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Nivel2.class);
                        startActivity(intentnivel2);
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo tengo algo similar en una aplicación, tengo creada una clase para guardar y obtener el valor del "nivel":

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Preferencias {


    private static String PREFS_KEY = "mypreferences";

    public static void setLevel(Context context, int level) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt("nivel", level);
        editor.commit();
    }



    public static int getLevel(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return  preferences.getInt("nivel", 0);
    }


}
```

Cuando accedes a `MainActivity` o tu activity principal y obtienes el valor de la preferencia para determinar el nivel:

```
    switch (Preferencias.getLevel(getApplicationContext())){

        case 0:
            //No realiza nada
            break;
        case 1:
            //Intent carga primer nivel
            break;
        case 2:
            //Intent carga segundo nivel
            break;
        case 3:
            //Intent carga tercer nivel
            break;
    }
```

para esto en cada Activity puedes guardar el valor del nivel para que al iniciar la aplicación determine a que "nivel" dirigirse, por ejemplo si te encuentras en el nivel 1 :

```
   Preferencias.setLevel(getApplicationContext(), 1 /* Nivel */);
```

Comment: Funciona de maravilla hasta que cierro la app y la vuelvo a abrir y al darle click en jugar, se detiene la app. Y no tengo emulador para saber que mensaje LOgCat me esta mandando. Sabes porque puede estar sucediendo esto?

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que estas realizando, tienes definidas las Activity en tu AndroidManifest.xml?. Si tienes dispositivo físico también puedes ver mensajes en el LogCat.

Comment: Listo, ya mismo agrego el código, y en cuanto al LogCat, no cuento con cable con el cual interactuar entre dispositivo y pc, las apps las mando todas inalambricamente con airdroid.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys tu respuesta si me sirvió, lo que pasa es que tenia errores en el cierre de mis activitys y por eso se me cerraba la app cuando la reiniciab; pero ahora funciona perfectamente y me guarda el ultimo nivel asi cierre por completo la app :) . Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Hola Johan!, recuerda que para resolver errores rápidamente hay que revisar el LogCat, que bueno que te ayudo la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Dfinitivamente si, de igual manera baje una app para registrar los mensajes LogCat en mi telefono que me sera de gran ayuda en el futuro :)